# Why do i get this error, Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

so im trying to make a test for my component a simple test that shows if the component was rendered

```
 test('Should render the movie info', () => {
    renderWithContext(<MovieInfo movie={mockMovies[0]} />);
    expect(screen.getByText('Terrifier 2')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

but i get this error:

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

the problem seems to have be about axios some how because it happens when trying to import axios.

```
 > 2 | import axios from 'axios';
        | ^
```

i have a jest.config.js file like this.

```
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig.json');

const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');
const { default: tsjPreset } = require('ts-jest');
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    ...tsjPreset.transform,
    '+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2|pdf)$':
      'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleDirectories: ['src', 'node_modules'],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(axios)/)'],
};
```

and i have installed ts-jest, @types/jest and jest-transform-stub as dependencies

i have looked on the internet and this seems to be about some jest config that im doing wrong but nothing i do works

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this to my package.json i think its a hacky way of doing it but is the only way it worked for me.

```
"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!axios)/\"",
```